# How to run Methods like Render and flash inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to run methods like Render and flash from model file inside rails. My code is this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :price, :released_on
validates :name, uniqueness: true

def self.to_csv(options = {})
 CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  csv << column_names
  all.each do |product|
    csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
end
end



def self.import(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path , headers:true) do |row|
  @product=Product.new(row.to_hash)
  if @product.valid?
     @product.save
    flash[:notice] = "Product created!"
    redirect_to(@product) and return
else

 redirect_to action: :index
 end
 end
 end
 end
```

When I run this and enter model I got an error that Flash method . Similarly Render Method not defined. any guesses.

Comment: The controller controls displaying the views, there's no meaning to trying to put it in the model. That code can be moved to the controller.

Comment: Also, please reformat your code. It's too hard to understand your code without indentaitions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You don't.

Longer answer: You're trying to do things in a way that don't suit the Rails way of working. There is a very solid separation between the things that display and the data underlying those things.

You need to rethink how these things fit together. The Controller is responsible for dealing with the models and then preparing the information for display by the View. Rather than create the flash in the model, use the controller to find out if the product was created and allow it to display the flash.